# Is installing pre-compiled software from tarballs against the Debian philosophy?

Tags: debian, software-installation

Probably the biggest argument for trying out Debian is its stability. In order to not break that stability, we have to follow a certain philosophy, which is to always install software from the official Debian repos and never ever [make install](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_.27make_install.27) stuff from random tarballs you find on the internet.

However, it is not clear to me yet if I should apply that mentality to pre-compiled software too. I have installed Apache OpenOffice and PyCharm from tarballs by just extracting them via `tar -xvzf file.tar.gz`. After that, I am either already able to run the program or have to install some `.deb` files (which conforms to the Debian philosophy, I suppose?), without ever having to "make installing".

I guess installing "random" `.deb` files could mess up my system, but apart from that, is there any way I could break my system this way?

Comment: Really depends on where you're untaring to...

Comment: I've been decompressing the files to `/opt/` and keep them there. If possible, I create symbolic links to the executables in `/usr/bin/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Debian Social Contract](https://www.debian.org/social_contract) section 4 says

> **Our priorities are our users and free software**
>
> We will be guided by the needs of our users and the free software community. We will place their interests first in our priorities. We will support the needs of our users for operation in many different kinds of computing environments. We will not object to non-free works that are intended to be used on Debian systems, or attempt to charge a fee to people who create or use such works. We will allow others to create distributions containing both the Debian system and other works, without any fee from us. In furtherance of these goals, we will provide an integrated system of high-quality materials with no legal restrictions that would prevent such uses of the system.

So I wouldn't say Debian has any objection to your practices. Certainly installing software to `/opt` should be fine; it may be better to link binaries into `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/usr/bin`, but that's a minor detail. (`/usr/bin` is supposed to be the domain of the package manager exclusively, but it is your system.)

Of course, there may be more "Debian-like" ways of doing things, but that depends on your specific use cases. I would suggest using the packaged [LibreOffice](https://tracker.debian.org/libreoffice) instead of Apache's OpenOffice. Installing "random" packages shouldn't break your system, as long as they come from the Debian archives. Whether or not you use Debian packages, there are countless ways of breaking your system; Debian developers do their best to avoid that happening if you do only use Debian packages, but there's no way to guarantee that...

If you wish to preserve the stability of your system:

- don't ever overwrite a package with non-packaged content;
- don't install non-packaged software in `/usr` (apart from `/usr/local`);
- be careful with initscripts or systemd units;
- don't install packages from random repositories (or Debian repositories apart from your main "suite"'s repository — so don't mix `stable` and `testing` etc. unless you know what you're doing).

Follow those rules and you should be safe enough. You can install software on top of the system provided by Debian, whether it's pre-compiled or you compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A "random deb" has two differences.

1. There's a natural way to uninstall it, which you know exists.  (I think standard autoconf projects provide `make uninstall`, but it's far from universal).
2. The names the package uses may conflict with other packages.  If filenames conflict, you'll get a warning at install time, so that's a nice improvement.  But if package names conflict, you could get very confusing results.

Detecting (some types of) filename conflicts could be a useful safety enhancement.  It'll stop you overwriting some system file which was already provided by a Debian package.  Uninstalls are pretty useful too.  However... if we're using stronger words like "random deb" and "not break that stability"?  Then I would say no, there isn't such a big difference in principle between that and `make install`.

Running individual programs from tarballs tends to be less intrusive.  However a second principle of Debian is the provision of security updates.  I would recommend against any possibility of opening Office files with the [insecure, unmaintained software](http://reddragdiva.tumblr.com/post/128873352708/urgent-get-the-hell-off-apache-openoffice-its) which you mentioned.  So the official (LibreOffice) packages would be preferable in most situations.

It would be slightly overblown to call this "the Debian philosophy".  It's not quite unique to Debian.  You could take the same attitude as a user of Ubuntu (LTS or otherwise), and I'd argue that it is a good starting point.  Also Debian has deeper philosophies, which would be more worthy of that word :).

Personally I'm running Debian on systems where I would expect Ubuntu LTS to look after me just as well.  My reason for avoiding Ubuntu has been that they've made up their own stuff, it's not impressed me and I've not been interested in dealing with it.  ("Unity", Mir, badmouthing of systemd.  And I want my wifi maintained in the open.  The way they integrate drivers makes me worry about long term maintenance).