# Where to place application plugins (.so)?

Tags: fhs

Where should I deploy application plugins? Nobody will ever use them. Does it make sense to put them in /usr/lib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to put them in `/usr/lib`, at least in some cases. According to the FHS, you should use an [application-specific directory under `/usr/lib`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s06.html), *e.g.* `/usr/lib/yourapp`. You can structure content there however you wish (see The Gimp, whose plugins end up in `/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins`, and many other examples in your own `/usr/lib`).

The usual general rules for `/usr` apply: if the software is packaged using the system's package manager, then `/usr/lib` [may be appropriate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283748/86440); otherwise it should go in `/usr/local/lib` (following the same pattern). (Thanks to [mobileink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/192921/mobileink) and [Barafu Albino](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/63941/barafu-albino) for the reminder.)

Comment: why /usr/lib/<app> and not /usr/local/lib/<app>?

Comment: It is /usr/lib for things installed with package manager and /usr/local for things installed by its own installer.